# invalid type conversion using size_t on a struct

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm trying to do something like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Id {
    int _age;
    char _name[10];
} Id;

int main()
{
    Id id = {10, "logan"};
    printf("%u\n", (size_t)id);  // Here is the problem.
}
```

The above code can't compile by `gcc`, anything wrong?

**The reason why I'm doing this**

Well, to tell the truth, I'm reading the code written by someone else, and what I did in the post is pretty much what the someone did in the code I'm reading. I can't even believe that will work, so I just try it myself. Moreover, I'm just using the lib compiled from the code, I'm not compiling the code at all. So I wonder if some compilation flags are set?

**UPDATE**

At someone's request, I post a screenshot of the code I saw, here it is.
[image]

In this `template`, I say `_Key` may be a user defined `struct`.

Comment: why do you want to convert a struct to size_t?

Comment: Perhaps you intended to use `sizeof` on the struct?

Comment: and id should be declared as struct Id

Comment: @chris: I've never heard of %z... is it nonstandard?

Comment: @Mehrdad, See the 7th column under "Argument type": http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @chris: I don't see it in other places, like on MSDN or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)... maybe it's a C++11 or C99 feature?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I noticed that too when I first saw it used. I figured it was just missed. It's in the C++ version, too. It's easy enough to test it against C++03.

Comment: It was in c99, but Microsoft aren't exactly famous in their quest for following the standards.

Comment: @Alcott: Well, everything's wrong. What are you trying to do? It is not possible to figure that out from your code. You have to explain it yourself.

Comment: @CyberDem0n: He typedef-ed the type, so plain `Id id` is enough.

Comment: @AndreyT, explained in my comment to paxidiablo's answer.

Comment: You use `%zu` or `%zx` or `%zX` or `%zo` (or at a pinch `%zd`, but that's a signed decimal); the `z` is a length modifier, like `l` is a length modifier.  It tells `printf()` et al to expect a value the size of `size_t`.

Comment: @AndreyT post was edited after my comment

Comment: @Alcott: What you have in your sample code can't possibly work. No way. You claim you saw something like that in someone else's code? You must have misinterpreted that someone else's code somehow. They were doing something different. Not this. Post a sample from the actual code you are reading, if possible.

Comment: Maybe the original author meant to write `printf("%u\n", *(size_t*)(&id));`, which should be written as `printf("%u\n", (size_t)(id._age));`

Comment: @behnam: I seriously doubt that that's what the OP wants to do. It would be much simpler to write `printf("%d\n", id._age);`. I suggest that guessing at the OP's intent is not useful until the OP comes back and shows us some real code.

Comment: @AndreyT, a screenshot uploaded.

Comment: Nobody asked for a screenshot. It's much better to copy-and-paste code *as text*.

Answer (score 2):

I think, if you want the size of that structure, you might want to use `sizeof(id)`, which returns a value of type `size_t`.

What you're attempting to do at the moment is to cast that structure to a `size_t` type, something that won't really work that well, if at all :-)

In other words:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(id));  // Here is the solution.
```

In addition (as you'll notice), the standard-blessed way of printing `size_t` values is with the `z` modifier:

> **z**:  Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a size_t or the corresponding signed integer type argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to size_t argument.

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, I'm reading the code written by someone else, and what I did in the post is pretty much what the someone did in the code I'm reading. I can't even believe that will work, so I just try it myself. Moreover, I'm just using the lib compiled from the code, I'm not compiling the code at all. So I wonder if some compilation flags are set?

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot `struct xhash` code you posted is C++ code, not C code.

However, while it is generally possible to make it work for class types in C++, I still very much doubt that this C++ code was even supposed to be used with class types. I would guess that the posted C++ `struct xhash` implementation is intended to be used as "fallback" implementation for *scalar types only*, while class types are required to provide their own implementations for hashing functor (by using template specialization mechanism, for example, or by defining completely different hashing functors for themselves).

Meanwhile, in C none of this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so in C++, this might compile?

Comment: @Alcott: An instantiation of `xhash` with a scalar type would compile. An instantiation with a non-scalar type would not.

Comment: @KeithThompson, which means if `_Key` is an `struct`, then it wouldn't compile, right?

Answer (score 0):

Update with keith's comment:

If you want to print age, you can(but behaviour is not defined,just implementation specific hack)

```
 int main() 
{     Id id = {10, "logan"}; 
    printf("%u\n", *((size_t*)((void*)&id)));  
}
```

To print size of ID,(returned type is size_t)

```
 int main() 
{     Id id = {10, "logan"}; 
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(id));  
}
```

Include **stddef.h** in your header.

C defines size_t as:-

> **size_t which is the *unsigned integer* type of the result of the sizeof
>   operator;**

Comment: That's not the problem. `size_t` is also defined in `<stdio.h>`. The problem is that you can't convert a struct to an integer.

Comment: @KeithThompson:- Updated , pls suggest...

Comment: So you take the address of `id`, convert it to `void*`, then convert that result to `size_t*`, and dereference the result. In effect, you're type-punning, treating the first few bytes of `id` as if they were a `size_t` object. This is extremely unlikely to be useful; note, for example, that `int` and `size_t` are not necessarily the same size. If you want to print `id._age`, just print `id._age`. And there's no indication that this is what the OP is looking for; we won't know that until the OP updates the question.

Answer (score 0):

`struct Id` is a struct type.  `size_t` is an integer type.  There is no conversion from struct types to integer types.  See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.4p2, "Cast operators":

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall
>   specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type, **and the operand
>   shall have scalar type.**

(Emphasis added.)

It's conceivable that a compiler might support such conversions as a language extension, but it's unlikely; I can't think of any reasonable semantics for it.

Reexamine the code you're working with. Either it doesn't compile (and you need to address that problem), or it does compile because it's not really doing that kind of conversion.

Oh, and don't define identifiers starting with an underscore; most of them are reserved to the implementation. `age` and `name` are perfectly good names; no need to call them `_age` and `_name`.